# save images to database

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-2

in my .net project i need to upload images to sql server.
my view class contains

```
<div class="editor-label">
    <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.image) %>
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.image, new { type = "file" })%>
    <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.image) %>
</div>
```

model class contains
 `public byte[] image { get; set; }`
. how to save this model to database
while directly saving this i,m getting error---> **The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or a non-white space character among the padding characters.**

Answer (score 0):

You Should use File type input

```
<%: Html.Label("Select Image") %>
<input id="File1" name="File1" type="file"  />
```

in code call that input like this i did in mvc

```
string imageSavePath = null;
            string fileName = null;
            if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
            {
                if (Request.Files[0].ContentLength > 0)
                {

                    fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + Path.GetExtension(Request.Files[0].FileName);
                    imageSavePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(Config.CategoryImageRelativePath), fileName);
                    Request.Files[0].SaveAs(imageSavePath);
                }
            }
```

i have saved base path for saving images in folder
    Config.CategoryImageRelativePath
it returns the folder path where images would be save

Answer (score -1):

Why you dont save the image in ftp server and set to database the location?

Comment: That would imply that every user of his web application would need and FTP Client to do the upload, and need and user for the upload, and to identify from the other files uploaded by other users, wich file is his, and to don't override an already existing file in the FTP folder.
And this, are only a few problems with the ftp upload solution.